# LinkedList .Add() only runs once

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm making a basic `LinkedList` following [this](http://csharp-algos.blogspot.com/2010/09/blog-post.html) tutorial. However, when I'm done the `list` only contains two elements, `"first"` and `"fourth"`. I put some break points in the code and found that the `Add` function of the `LinkedList` class only runs once. Each succesive `Add` goes into the `Node(object data)` method of the `Node` class. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Node
{
    public object data;
    public Node next;
    public Node(object data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
public class LinkedList
{
    private Node head;
    private Node current;
    public void Add(Node n)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = n;
            current = head;
        }
        else
        {
            current.next = n;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.Add(new Node("first"));
        list.Add(new Node("second"));
        list.Add(new Node("third"));
        list.Add(new Node("fourth"));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the answer that `list only contains two elements, "first" and "fourth"`? Could it be something wrong in PrintNodes method?

Comment: Is there any other code you're not showing us that modifies `current`? If there is, it has a high chance of making Add do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Using this basic print method with your code :

```
public void Print()
{
    Node curr = head;
    while(true)
    {
        if(curr == null)
           return;
         Console.WriteLine(curr.data.ToString());
         curr = curr.next;
    }
}
```

Return the correct result : [live example](https://ideone.com/8LHYMt).

> first
>
> second
>
> third
>
> fourth

Your error must be with your printing routine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code, i guess you are checking only the LinkedList nodes while debugging, which will only shows the head and the current values.

Just try this,

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
            list.Add(new Node("first"));
            list.Add(new Node("second"));
            list.Add(new Node("third"));
            list.Add(new Node("fourth"));
            list.PrintNodes();
        }

    }
    public class Node
    {
        public object data;
        public Node next;
        public Node(object data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
    public class LinkedList
    {
        private Node head;
        private Node current;
        public void Add(Node n)
        {
            if (head == null)
            {
                head = n;
                current = head;
            }
            else
            {
                current.next = n;
                current = current.next;
            }

        }
        public void PrintNodes()
        {
            while (head != null)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(head.data);
                head = head.next;

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```